# Calculate cache size in android for a particular package

Tags: android, caching, android-activity

I'm trying to develop an  Android app that could calculate cache size, So far I was unable to calculate all app cache in android, but recently I came across `PackageStats` class, problem with `PackageStats` class is there is a variable `public long cacheSize` it always reurns `0`, Here is my code

```
PackageStats pStats = new PackageStats("/data/data/com.android.browser/cache");
System.out.println("Cache Size -> "+pStats.cacheSize);
```

Here I'm always getting `0` actually cache size of `com.android.browser` package is is `884KB`
Please help me to solve this riddle, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just try this:

```
long f=0;
File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
for (File f:files) {
    size = size+f.length();

}
```

**EDIT**
Would the bellow methods throw an exception?

```
getCacheDir().length() or getExternalCacheDir().length()
```

Comment: Doesn't work, `Force Close` comes, eventhough I'm running code in `AsyncTask` only I'm getting Force Close

Comment: This code shouldn't initiate a Force Close. Perhaps something else is causing it?

Comment: Actually I checked this in plain java, it really worked for me, but when it comes to android then its a prob.

Comment: Hence my previous comment. This code does work, and perhaps it's something else that's making it not work. What kind of an exception are you getting anyway?

Comment: Which line are you getting the exception at?

Comment: In this line `File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();`